# How come terminal processes are paused when display sleeps?

Tags: terminal, sleep-wake, cpu

I'm running some long-running CPU intensive scripts, but I've noticed that the CPU utilisation becomes 0 when the *display* sleeps. I've already kept the machine awake using `caffeine`. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: what OS is it ? on what Mac ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm on 10.13.6 and MBP 2014.

Answer (score 1):

In High Sierra there is a 2 setting in System Preferences > Energy for that. Enable Prevent computer from sleeping....or/and set Display sleep to Never.

[image]

Comment: I've tried checking 'Prevent computer from sleeping...' but the process is still suspended when the display sleeps. I'll try setting Display sleep to Never.

Comment: you might have to restart for the settings to become permanent